# Spring Roo Configuration Error: "Path required"

Tags: spring-roo

I just started looking into Spring Roo.

I:

- Checked out a project into Spring Tool Suite.
- Converted it into a Maven project.
- Added Spring Project Nature.
- Added Roo Project Nature.

But when I opened the Roo shell in STS, I got `roo> Path required`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Download Spring Roo from :http://docs.spring.io/downloads/nightly/release-download.php?project=ROO
You have to provide Roo installation path to IDE.
Window-->Preferences-->Spring-->Roo Support-->Add. (Till Parent of bin folder)

Comment: Hi SpursP,  thanks for replying.  I've checked in Window -> Perferences -> Spring -> Roo Support. Roo 1.2.3.RELEASE (included with STS) was check. It looks like this is where we specify which Roo version we want to run the Roo shell from. I don't have problem running the Roo shell.  I'm having the problem with the error "Path required". Other than this error message.  Everything appears to work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error after upgrading from an earlier version of roo to the latest (1.3.1.RC2). Following the official upgrade instructions only got me so far:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/upgrade.html

After making all these changes, there were a number of errors in the application, which stemmed from changes all over the place. Some were changes to roo, some were changes as a result of upgrading to the latest libraries (like hibernate). After resolving all the compilation errors, roo was able to startup normally and resume normal operation